# SFML Graphics module linked partially

Tags: linker, sfml, lnk2001

I have linked sfml-graphics-d, sfml-system-d and sfml-window-d and everything was working just fine, until code that was working fine yesterday started throwing LNK2001 for sf::RenderStates.
What confuses me the most is that other members of Graphics.hpp work just fine except for sf::Color. Has anybody ever encountered this "partial linking" or whatever it is called?

Comment: Make sure that all your dlls match the header version. You're probably using SFML 2.x header with SFML 2.y binaries.

Comment: I don't think i fully understand you. I did make a new project on a new install of the latest version of SFML, which did not solve the issue. Were you asking whether the version of files in SFML\lib matched the version of files in SFML\include ?

Comment: dlls, libs, whatever.. I'm not used to Windows terminology. What I meant was that, on your system, somewhere, you probably have a bad mix of two version of SFML. Make sure that's not the case: remove them all and perform a clean install.

Comment: I'll get to that as soon as I'll have a moment, huge thanks for the reply.